# How to filter the_content() function in php to only return one certain div class?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Using the function `the_content()` return the whole content of a post. However I only want to return the content of one div class of this post. Is there a way to filter the function or are other methods possible to achieve the same result?

My content

```
<div class="hi"> Hello </div>
<div class="bye"> good bye</div>
```

Using `the_content()` returns

```
Hello
good bye
```

How I only want this returned

```
Hello
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$content = get_the_content(); 
$doc->loadHTML($content);
$element = $doc->getElementByClass('hi');
$elementContent = $doc->textContent();
```

Comment: This gives me an error saying "empty string supplied on line" `$doc->loadHTML($content)`

Comment: yes you need to assign the $content to the content, I assume you have WordPress so you need to have something like $content = get_the_content(); at the beginning

Comment: I tried that which gives me another error " Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_the_content() on nul"

Comment: are you using WordPress ?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/

Comment: Yes, I am using wordpress and I made a mistake using ´->´ instead of ´=´. However now it says ": Call to undefined method DOMDocument::getElementByClass() "